# PCA on Gaussian gene expression data

Tags: normal-distribution, pca, bioinformatics

I am aware that PCA done on Gaussian distributed data ensures the uncorrelatedness as well as independence of each factor. I am having difficulty understanding what the 'Gaussian distribution refers to'.

For example in gene expression data. I have a matrix with each row indicating specific gene and each column indicating each individual. If I perform an PCA on this matrix hoping to uncover several expression patterns, what does 'Gaussian distribution' refer to here? Is it the expression of each gene in specific pattern or the expression of single gene among individual?

Comment: if you have expression of each gene yes/no than the data are not gaussian and you should use something like a correspondence analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In a gene expression matrix, each row represents a gene and each column represents a cell. Each entry in the matrix represents the expression level of the particular gene in the particular cell.

Our variables are $X_1,...,X_p$, where $X_i$ denotes the expression level in cell $i$ for $i \in \{1,...,p\}$.

The Gaussian assumption is that the random vector $\boldsymbol{X}=(X_1,...,X_p)'$
follows a multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$.